# Error al cargar CSV en c++

Tags: c++, csv

Quiero leer un archivo CSV. El código compila pero no me muestra nada en pantalla. ¿Cuál será mi error?

Traté de cambiar la primera opción, que era con un `for`, pero no me muestra nada aún. Lo que sucede es que quiero usar árboles y quiero primero organizarlo en esta estructura los datos, ya que sí he leído CSV antes pero sin involucrar una estructura.

Contenido del CSV:

```
1,luis,descircion,18,10  
2,pedro,descripcion,20,1  
3,juan,decripcion,15,2
```

Código C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// DEFINITION
struct items {
    int ID;
    string name;
    string desc;
    string price;
    string pcs;
};

vector <items> a;

void step1() {

    string namefile, line;
    int counter = 0;

    cout << "Name of the file:" << endl;
    cin >> namefile;

    ifstream file;

    file.open(namefile.c_str());

    if( !file.is_open()) {

        cout << "File "<< namefile <<" not found." << endl;
        exit(-1);

    }

    while ( getline( file, line) ) { // To get the number of lines in the file
        counter++;
    }

    items* item = new items[counter]; // Add number to structured array

    /*for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

        file >> item[i].ID >> item[i].name >> item[i].desc >> item[i].price >> item[i].pcs;

    }*/

    for (items i;
      (file >> i.ID).ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',')
      && getline(file, i.name, ',')
      && getline(file, i.desc, ',')
      && getline(file, i.price, ',')
      && getline(file, i.pcs); ) {
    a.push_back(i);
}



    cout << item[1].name << endl;

    file.close();
}


int main(){
step1();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lo primero que te falta es un `file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);` para volver a posicionar el cursor de lectura al comienzo del archivo. En cuanto a ese bucle, voy a comprobarlo. ¿Puedes usar una lista en lugar de una matriz estática de datos?

Comment: Entiendo y donde pondria eso?, si podria lo de la lista

Comment: Ya he encontrado el segundo error. Estás introduciendo los valores en `a`, pero luego muestras `item`. Redactando respuesta.

Comment: Trate de mostrar a pero brindaba lo mismo, me imagino que es por lo segundo que me indicas, como lo podria corregir?

Comment: Ya está redactada la respuesta, espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores que has cometido en tu código:

- Usas un `vector` llamado `a` para almacenar los datos, pero declaras una matriz llamada `items` que es la que tratas de mostrar su contenido (obviamente no tendrá nada aunque tu código funcionara correctamente).
- Recorres el archivo completamente para contar sus líneas y luego no haces un `seekg` para volver a posicionar el archivo al principio (no quedará nada que leer del archivo en tu bucle).
- Para acceder a elementos de un `vector` necesitas llamar a `at()` con el índice del elemento que deseas mostrar.

Código funcional:

```
void step1() {
    string namefile, line;
    cout << "Name of the file:" << endl;
    cin >> namefile;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(namefile.c_str());
    if(!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "File "<< namefile <<" not found." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    /* No necesitas un recuento de líneas ni reservar elementos para una matriz
        que no vas ni a utilizar (porque usas el vector) */
    for (items i;
        (file >> i.ID).ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',')
        && getline(file, i.name, ',')
        && getline(file, i.desc, ',')
        && getline(file, i.price, ',')
        && getline(file, i.pcs);
    ) {
        a.push_back(i);
    }
    /* Al no ser una matriz, debes usar "at(n)" para localizar un dato */
    cout << a.at(1).name << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en línea en [este gitpod](https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/ojgarciab/360436-stackoverflow-es) y el código fuente disponible en este [repositorio github](https://github.com/ojgarciab/360436-stackoverflow-es).

Comment: Muchas Gracias..

Comment: De nada, un placer. No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.